# Улучшить пояснение к получению знака за проверку

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Предлагаю фразу

> Знаки за проверку присуждаются один раз за одну очередь.

заменить на

> Знаки за проверку присуждаются по одному разу за каждую очередь.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Применил перевод. Будет на сайте после подгрузки Transifex и последующей сборки.